# automatically expanding array in .NET?

Tags: .net, perl, collections

Does .NET have anything similar to Perl arrays, which are indexed numerically but automatically expand as needed?  It would work like this:

```
var x = new DreamArray<string>();

x[6] = "foo";  // x automatically has 7 elements
x[10] = "bar"; // now it has 11
```

Comment: People are suggesting ArrayList and List, but you can't just add to them like: x[5] = "foo"

Comment: And I thought of HashTable and Dictionary, but they have more overhead than a numerically indexed collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but it could be easily emulated with:

```
class MagicArray<T> : Dictionary<int, T> {}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but you should use `SortedList<int, T>` instead of `Dictionary<int, T>` as it also allows indexed access to the values.

Comment: @Obalix, Dictionary was the first thing that came to my mind when writing the snippet.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `List<string>` instead of an array. You will have to call `List.Add("item")` to add to the list though.

Comment: The documentation on the Generic List can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: To add that, a List<string> is literally just a wrapper around a string Array.

Comment: @Jonathan: True, but it does not increment when an item is added but increments in chunks, thus providing a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Hash Tables & ArrayLists are the first 2 things to come to mind. They're not used exactly the same, though you could use a hashtable in a pretty similar manner.

See [C# Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz%28VS.80%29.aspx) for usage, examples, and more ideas

Answer (score 1):

You could easily write your own. You would have to implement the ICollection interface and then aggregate a standard List, etc. But, in the indexer property, if the index is greater than the Capacity, simply change the Capacity property to the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Lists would be the closest.  Just use List()

Comment: But you can't just add to List like: x[5] = "foo"